# add country code and city to a dataset given coordinates

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, reverse-geocoding

How can I add country code and city given coordinates . The coordinates exists as a column with values like  (52.3992723, 13.3883492). I am using code workbook to do this .

Sample dataset

```
Person,Coordinates
Id1, 52.3992723, 13.3883492
Id2, 57.3992723, 13.3883492
```

Code Sample :

```
import reverse_geocoder as rg
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

map_state = F.udf(lambda x : rg.search(x)[0]['admin2'])
return(df.withColumn('newCol',map_state(F.col('coordinates'))))
```

Comment: Could you please add expected output that you want on input data?